# Get the position of the clicked list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, indexing

lets say we have this markup:

```
<header>
   <nav>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="">first (not)</a></li>
         <li><a href="">second</a></li>
         <li><a href="">third</a></li>
        <!-- ... more here -->
      </ul>
   </nav>
</header>
```

I found out about [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) function

I'm trying like this:

```
$('body').on('click','header :not(li:first-child a) a',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     alert($(this).parents('ul').find('li').index(this));
});
```

but it would allways alert: `-1`

what am I missing?

Comment: should be just: alert($(this).parents('ul li').index());  in your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to get just parent:

```
alert( $( this ).parent().index() );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
$('body').on('click','header li + li a',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     console.log($(this).closest('li').index());
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7As8q/)

The problem was, I think, the `this` in the `index` method; as `index` returns the index of the currently-matched element against the selector provided to the method and there is a: only *one* current/`this` node, and b: that current node is *not* amongst the siblings of the element of which you're trying to find the index. Hence the return of `-1` (in JavaScript the traditional result if the element isn't found within a given array).

Also, I changed your selector; I was assuming that you wanted to find the index of the `li` that wasn't the *first* `li`? But I may have misunderstood the selector or your intent.

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).